# Xcode KEEPS Crashing when archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, archiving

This is the error console:
    Xcode just started crashing YESTERDAY, I have NO Clue why! I was arching my app to submit it, but I couldn't.
    I have tried reinstalling and other attempts, PLEASE HELP!

This is the code when It crashed and came up with the crash report
     Process:         Xcode [1150]
   Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
   Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
   Version:         4.3.2 (1177)
   Build Info:      IDEApplication-1177000000000000~6
   App Item ID:     497799835
    App External ID: 7171108
    Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [352]

```
Date/Time:       2012-05-13 08:15:21.649 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          111561 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           38
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  155115 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   25
Anonymous UUID:                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Crashed Thread:  10  Dispatch queue: IDEArchiveManager

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000




 Application Specific Information:
    ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002
    UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4039cb820
    UserInfo: (null)
    Hints: None
    Backtrace:
      0  0x00007fff889ecfaa __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
      1  0x00007fff8a778d5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
      2  0x00007fff88a792ae -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
      3  0x00007fff889d9e73 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
      4  0x00007fff889d9c88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
      5  0x0000000101323f62 +[IDEArchivedApplication archivedApplicationInfoForApplicationInArchiveProductsDirectory:] (in IDEFoundation)
      6  0x0000000101322885 +[IDEArchive createArchiveWithName:schemeName:platform:products:auxiliaryFiles:usingFileManager:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
      7  0x000000010131ea3e __block_global_0 (in IDEFoundation)
      8  0x0000000100c084c0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)
      9  0x00007fff8c2b48ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
     10  0x00007fff8c2b610a _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
     11  0x00007fff8c2b5f66 _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
     12  0x00007fff8c2b5760 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
     13  0x00007fff8a4b23da _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
     14  0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)

    objc[1150]: garbage collection is ON
    NSURL
    abort() called

    Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e66167a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e660d71 mach_msg + 73
    2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e653d84 mach_port_insert_member + 131
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981e00 __CFRunLoopRun + 1104
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8367931f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8368051b ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
    7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff83680456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff892b8f5d _DPSNextEvent + 659
    9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff892b8861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff892b519d -[NSApplication run] + 470
    11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89533b88 NSApplicationMain + 867
    12  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x0000000100b62eec 0x100b62000 + 3820

    Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e6637e6 kevent + 10
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b65be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b514e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

    Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e66167a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e660d71 mach_msg + 73
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff889796fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981e64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0baffb +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 335
    6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af74e -[NSThread main] + 68
    7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af6c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e66167a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e660d71 mach_msg + 73
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff889796fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981e64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x00000001082a4ee8 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 298
    6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af74e -[NSThread main] + 68
    7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af6c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e662df2 __select + 10
    1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff889cacdb __CFSocketManager + 1355
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e66167a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e660d71 mach_msg + 73
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff889796fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981e64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f060f9f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
    6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f060e8b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 62
    7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af74e -[NSThread main] + 68
    8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af6c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 6:: CVDisplayLink
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e662bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b42a6 _pthread_cond_wait + 890
    2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8927363f CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 279
    3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff89272aa5 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 559
    4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8927285d _ZL13startIOThreadPv + 148
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e662bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b4274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
    2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000104893b48 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 348
    3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af74e -[NSThread main] + 68
    4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f0af6c6 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 10 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IDEArchiveManager
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e662ce2 __pthread_kill + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b27d2 pthread_kill + 95
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4a3a7a abort + 143
    3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010173560e +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:] + 506
    4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000101736280 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 603
    5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000100c084e9 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke_0 + 57
    6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b48ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
    7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b610a _dispatch_queue_drain + 264
    8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b5f66 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 54
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b5760 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198
    10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b23da _pthread_wqthread + 316
    11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 11:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 12:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 13:: Dispatch queue: Garbage Collection Work Queue
    0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88951e86 CFRelease + 662
    1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88959f43 __CFURLDeallocate + 35
    2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f1bdbb2 -[NSURL(NSURL) finalize] + 96
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a77757c finalizeOneObject + 53
    4   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8402107e Auto::foreach_block_do(auto_zone_cursor*, void (*)(void*, void*), void*) + 94
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a7774ac batchFinalize + 53
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a7775fb batchFinalizeOnTwoThreads + 91
    7   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff84021019 Auto::Zone::invalidate_garbage(unsigned long, void**) + 73
    8   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8400e7db auto_collect_internal(Auto::Zone*, unsigned int) + 459
    9   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8400a21a __auto_zone_collect_block_invoke_0 + 74
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b48ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
    11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b610a _dispatch_queue_drain + 264
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b5f66 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 54
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c2b5760 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198
    14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b23da _pthread_wqthread + 316
    15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 14:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 15:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 16:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 17:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 18:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 19:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 20:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e663192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b2594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b85 start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 21:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e66167a mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e660d71 mach_msg + 73
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff889796fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981e64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88981676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    5   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff84d9c2f2 _ZL20SpotlightQueryThreadPv + 434
    6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Thread 22:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e662e42 __semwait_signal + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a466dea nanosleep + 164
    2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff887233bb cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 42
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b08bf _pthread_start + 335
    4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a4b3b75 thread_start + 13

    Is there any other solutions to try before I quit?
I need help, Thanks
Any solutions
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [report that to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com). It looks like they've got an array that they think should be a dictionary (perhaps it's a bug in parsing the project file).

Comment: I submitted a bug, Is there ANYTHING I can do to get my app submitted?

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. Are you seeing this on Mac OS Yosemite?

For now I'd recommend you switch back to Xcode 5.1, and upload your build